# NetworkManager StrongSwan No Certificate

Tags: network-manager, vpn, certificates

I have used vpnc to connect to a VPN successfully, but it has that bug that it disconnects after 8.5 hours. I want to use StrongSwan. It asks for a certificate. I don't have a certificate. In vpnc, I had an IPSec name and IPSec password. How to I configure StrongSwan to use the name/password (which is not my personal username/password) instead of a certificate?

An alternative... Is there a way to pull a certificate from a VPN server? Turns out that Google for anything like "How to get a certificate from a VPN server" doesn't turn up anything useful.

Comment: you need a setup package from the VPN server to get the user Cert for it; contact the VPN provider?

Answer (score 0):

Q: How to I configure StrongSwan to use the name/password (which is not my personal username/password) instead of a certificate?

A: You (sort of) don't.
First StrongSwan will need that you have the public certificate of the CA that is used. So it does not work without certificates.

Then there are a few option how you can configure your VPN Gateway to accept connections. If you only want to use username and password, then your VPN Gateway has to be configured as IKEv2 with EAP-MSCHAPv2. Other configuration options will involve a combination of only private/public keys or private/public keys with username and password.

Long story short, your VPN Gateway provider is the only one that can tell you how you need to configure your system.

Q: An alternative... Is there a way to pull a certificate from a VPN server?

Yes, if you have (root) access to it, otherwise no.